# Can I bend sprites in Cocos2D?

Tags: c++, ios, sprite

I'm using Cocos2D, or more specifically Cocos2D-x to make a platformer-shooter game. I already have the platformer part, but I want to make my character shoot. I've seen in many ios games characters are able to shoot wherever they want and I wonder, do they make tons of sprites for this, because they can also fun while  aiming at other sides, or do they sort of bend their sprites. How can I achieve this effect? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358273/cocos2d-help-how-to-rotate-a-sprite-continuously-and-generate-child-sprites-in) deals with rotation.

I believe it's feasible to compose a shooting figure from a sprite featuring the body and another sprite, which rotates on top of a joint and is composed of arm and gun. Does it look good? There's definitely some artistic skills required to make the joint look natural. An alpha channel could be enough though -- or some people deliberately make the heroes wear futuristic armors with spherical joints.